# I installed Ubuntu on my notebook but it does not restart

Tags: bios

I bought an Acer notebook and it came with Windows 10 Pro installed. I cannot format to install Ubuntu 18.04. I spoke with the manufacturer's support and she said that the Acer is blocked out of the operating system. Does someone have any ideas of how I can solve this problem?

Thank you for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: If you read the answers on the linked question and nothing is helpful, you will need to clarify what exactly the manufacturer support told you, i.e. how they block other OS's.